# how to catch exception 'ex' in C# to give http response

Tags: c#, try-catch, jwt

I want to catch the ex. So, I can return the error code value

Can anyone help me?

```
public string Decrypt(string cipherText, string sid)
{
    RNCryptor.Decryptor D = new Decryptor();
    string DecryptedString = "";
    int errcode = 0;
    if (Prod == false)
    {
        DecryptedString = cipherText;
    }
    else
    {
    try
    {
        DecryptedString = D.Decrypt(cipherText, sid + SigningKey);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        // i want to return errcode 601 to give my response to HTTP
    }
    }
    return DecryptedString.Trim();
}
```

And this is my another code :

```
if (ErrCode < 0)
{
    string errMessage = "Decrypt error";
    return Content((HttpStatusCode)(ErrCode * (-1)),errMessage);
}
```

this is where my Decrypt method is used

```
public dynamic GetPikachu(string sid, FormDataCollection form)
    {
        string StrPikachu = Decrypt(form.Get("pikachu"), sid);
        return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(StrPikachu);
    }
```

Comment: use `out` parameter to resolve this. Refer: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t3c3bfhx.aspx

Comment: I would say redesign your solution, because `Decrypt` function should not return HTTP code in any case. Maybe skip this `try` - `catch` inside `Decrypt` and surround with them invocation of  this method?

Comment: @BalagurunathanMarimuthu ill try it, thanks. but still need another option

Comment: @PawełHemperek invocation? i cant understand sorry:( i'm fresh grad

Comment: @Richard Please show code, where you are using this `Decrypt` method

Comment: @PawełHemperek i edited the question thanks :D

Comment: I must admit - I didn't see Pokemons coming to this thread, but fair enough :-D Like I said - I would move `try` and `catch` to your `GetPikachu` method and return your error code there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to do what you want from inside Decrypt method is to throw:

```
throw new HttpResponseException((HttpStatusCode)601);
```

Yet the easiest is often not the right way to go. You can change your:

```
public string Decrypt(string cipherText, string sid)
```

to

```
bool TryDecrypt(string cipherText, string sid, out string result)
```

and simply return false in the exception handler. Then process this value in controller.